# How to implement a method to return Iterator of files recursively in Java

Tags: java, iterator

I want to implement a method like this:

```
public Iterator<File> getFiles(String root) {
  // return an Iterator looping through all files in root and all files in sub-directories of roots (recursively)
}
```

In C#, this can easily be implemented with the `yield return` keyword.  In Java, I suspect I have to end up writing a lot of complicated code to get it done.  Is there any good solution to this problem?

**Edit:** I want the returned Iterator to be "lazy", i.e. only return a new File when `next()` is invoked.  (That is the behavior C#'s `yield return` offers.)

Comment: Can you please explain why you want it to be lazy?

Comment: Because I don't necessarily go through all the next(), I might want to stop in between (i.e. users click Stop).  Eager-load of a very deep directories structure is expensive if we don't need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code might be your  solution http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3532

Answer (score 3):

[Apache Commons FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) offers [iterator](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#iterateFiles%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean%29) methods to iterate through directories and subdirectories. That does what you want and should save you a lot of work.

e.g.

`Iterator fi = iterateFiles(new File("."), String[] {".csv"}, true)`

to find all .csv files below the current directory.

Comment: As I look into the source code, it turns out that the code adds all files into a collection and finally calls iterator() method on that collection.  I want a lazy, not eager-loading Iterator.  I have updated the original post.  

Thanks for bringing this up anyway, will come very handy in other occasions.

Comment: Ok. In that case I think you may need a recursive method and provide your own callback object. I don't of any off the top of my head, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I might have missed something, but why don't you just make your own iterator 
class which implements iterator. Then you just need to implement a lazy
next() method in you iterator.

Comment: Sure that's something I would do unless somebody already solved that problem in smarter ways that I could possibly come up with.  And this answer seems to suggest 1 of such solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785228/how-to-implement-a-method-to-return-iterator-of-files-recursively-in-java/785236#785236